# composer.json to install vendors on development environment differently

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

How to set composer.json to install some vendors on development environment different than on production eg. PHPUnit install on development and not on production.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [require-dev](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev) section for this:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.7"
}
```

If you want to install only packages from "require", e.g. on your production server, you can do it like this:

```
composer install --no-dev
```

It will exclude "require-dev" packages, see [`composer install` options docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install) for more.

Comment: And run `php composer.phar install --dev` after

Comment: how composer know which enviroment is dev ? Only --dev in argument while instaling is option ?

Comment: @Inurosen No need for that, it's on by default. To turn it off add `--no-dev` (see [`composer install` options](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install)).

Comment: @fico7489 It's not related to prod (site.com)/dev (localhost) as we know it. It's only on your root `composer.json` on by default. Meaning on production, you'd install composer it via `composer install --no-dev`. To exclude all development-only packages.